# Gluten-Free beer recommendations?

Tags: recommendations, specialty-beers, gluten-free

I have Celiac and cannot drink normal beers.  (which I miss)  I love the taste of beer, and the only ones I have found and available in stores that taste decent are RedBridge and New Grist. (not a fan of cider beers).  I am looking for new gluten free beers with great taste and are truly gluten free, and not just gluten reduced.  Would love to hear recommendations from you.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not gluten intolerant so I don't have any experience myself, but I'd advise searching BeerAdvocate as their ratings are generally reliable: https://www.beeradvocate.com/search/?q=gluten+free

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [What are some of the most common ingredients used in gluten-free beers?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/4811/5064)